# How to use if condition in for loop according to increasing value - javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

Below is my code. I want to use some generic variable in if else condition instead of hardcoding 1,4,7 or 2,5,8 etc

```
for (let i = 1; i <= endValue; i++) {
  if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 7) //1,4,7,10 and so on..
  {
    console.log('value a');
  }
  else if (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8) //2,5,8,11,14 and so on..
  {
    console.log('value b');
  }
  else if (i == 3 || i == 6 || i == 9) //3,6,9,12,15 and so on..
  {
    console.log('value c');
  }
}
```

Tried multiple conditions but nothing works perfectly. Can someone please help.

```
    for (j=1;j<=krcount;j++){ 
    let x=1,y=2,z=j=3;
    if(j==x||j==x+3){             
        console.log('Manual');
    }
    else if(j==y||j==y+3){  
        console.log('Task');
    }
    else if(j==z||j==z+3){ 
        console.log('JIRA');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you want to achieve?

Comment: edited. can you please check and help

Answer (score 1):

You could check the remainder with three with an offset.

```
i % 3 === 1 // 1 4 7 ...
i % 3 === 2 // 2 5 8 ...
i % 3 === 0 // 3 6 9 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use remainder (%) operator.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= endValue; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 1) //1,4,7,10 and so on..
  {
    console.log('value a');
  }
  else if (i % 3 === 2) //2,5,8,11,14 and so on..
  {
    console.log('value b');
  }
  else if (i % 3 === 0) //3,6,9,12,15 and so on..
  {
    console.log('value c');
  }
}
```